# MySQL query using Inner join with pivot (wordpress)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, pivot-table, inner-join

Need help with this MySQL DB table in my WordPress, I want to pivot this table data, and here is my inner join query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry_meta`.`meta_id`,
  `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry`.`entry_id`,
  `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry`.`form_id`,
  `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry_meta`.`meta_key`,
  `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry_meta`.`meta_value`

FROM
  `xpa642996449419`.`wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry` 
  INNER JOIN `xpa642996449419`.`wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry_meta`
    ON (
      `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry`.`entry_id` = `wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry_meta`.`entry_id`
    ) 
WHERE form_id = 1580;
```

**TABLE RESULT**

| meta_id | entry_id | form_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1391 | 241 | 1580 | hidden-1 | 40 |
| 1392 | 241 | 1580 | hidden-2 | Shaun Ryan |
| 1393 | 241 | 1580 | date-1 | 06/06/2022 |
| 1394 | 241 | 1580 | name-1 | Stephen Smith |
| 1395 | 241 | 1580 | number-1 | 7.00 |
| 1396 | 241 | 1580 | number-2 | 13.00 |
| 1397 | 241 | 1580 | number-3 | 35.6 |
| 1398 | 241 | 1580 | textarea-2 | Assisted living |
| 1399 | 241 | 1580 | textarea-1 | Arrived at Stephens house |

**my pivot query without inner join:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT entry_id,
  
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "hidden-1" THEN meta_value END) AS 'hidden-1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "hidden-2" THEN meta_value END) AS 'hidden-2',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "date-1" THEN meta_value END) AS 'date-1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "name-1" THEN meta_value END) AS 'name-1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "number-1" THEN meta_value END) AS 'number-1',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "number-2" THEN meta_value END) AS 'number-2',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "number-3" THEN meta_value END) AS 'number-3',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "textarea-2" THEN meta_value END) AS 'textarea-2',
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = "textarea-1" THEN meta_value END) AS 'textarea-1'

FROM wp_4w9s6k45mv_frmt_form_entry_meta
GROUP BY
  entry_id
ORDER BY
  entry_id ASC;
```

Comment: What did you try?  How did it fail?  Syntax error?  Wrong output?  Something else?

Comment: I didn't know what is the correct syntax in pivot query having inner join

Comment: Think of it this way:  A `SELECT` doing a `JOIN` creates a "table" with all the columns of both tables,  Then it looks at the `SELECT` clause to decide what to display.